# OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Tags: openssl, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to download homestead/laravel with vagrant.
I'm selecting vmware_desktop box, but i'm getting this error :

> OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

i have lunched this command : `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`
i tried also `--insecure` option but i got the same error

What i have to do. Help please

Comment: yes duplicate but this didn't help me

Comment: can you download the box using `wget https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/6.3.0/providers/vmware_desktop.box` trying adding `--no-check-certificate` flag if you still face ssl issue

Comment: wget ? have i to install some packages ?

Comment: wget is an example if you dont have the package installed use any other methods to download